# WPF .net 4.0: Textbox resets caret position when binding with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I've got the following Situation:

- TextBox which is bound to a property:

> ```
> <TextBox Text="{Binding Settings.ClientName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
> ```

- The property ClientName stores its value in the unterlying structures and does NOT call Notifyon the property changed event. instead the underlying structures send an event to refresh the UI after they processed the value . If such an event is fired, the ClientNameProperty is set correctly and Notify is called for this property.

the problem is that if i enter any text, the caret seems to jump to the first position in the textbox, actuall reversing any string i enter. "abcd" becomes "dcba"

I noticed that this behaviour occured after we migrated to Net 4.0.

Are there any good solutions out there?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you show some code how you are refreshing your UI and notifying property changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in behavior that would do that. That problem is likely to come from your processing.

On a side note, if you want the TextBox to change from code-behind as well as from user input, you want to make it Two-Way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Settings.ClientName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**EDIT:**
You could also make the ClientName a dependency property (propdp snippet in vs2010). That would automatically fully support binding(/styling/animation), and gives you the possibility to act when the value changes as well as to coerce it back through callback delegates.
Last but not least, you still wouldn't need your Settings class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) is a place to start (msdn).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try with the explicit two way binding. However: I read on the internet that the binidng behaviour has changed for textboxes, and i notice a different behaviour since we upgraded to 4.0.

I Just noticed that if i call notify immediately after updating the property (and not only when reacting on the event), it works as expected.

Ay further ideas?

Comment: The binding on TextBox updates on LostFocus, regular bindings update on PropertyChanged by default. I'll edit my answer with another solution.

Comment: Yes, I need to update the Property as soon as any text is changed, as i cannot rely on LostFocus

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are suffering from this behavior change in the WPF TextBox: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588343/changed-behaviour-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-0-of-wpf-textbox-formatting-when-propertychanged-is-used-as-updatesourcetrigger (Changed behaviour from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0 of WPF TextBox formatting when PropertyChanged is used as UpdateSourceTrigger)

Comment: Link only answer: now the link is dead, answer is not helpful.